# Determining all groups of order $12$ whose quotient can be $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

As the title says, I would like to find all the groups $G$ of order $12$ such that there exists a normal subgroup $H \subseteq G$ with $G/H \simeq S_3$ ($S_3$ is the symmetric group of degree $3$).

**The following is my line of thought, and I would like you to check if this is correct**:

I need to check if the possible choices of $G$ can have such a normal subgroup $H$, and then check if $G/H \simeq S_3$. Due to cardinality reasons, such a subgroup $H$ must be isomorphic to $C_2$ (cyclic group of order 2).

The groups of order $12$ are the following (cf. [Groupprops](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_12)):

- $C_{12}$ (cyclic group of order $12$),
- $D_6$ (dihedral group of order $6 \cdot 2$),
- $A_4$ (alternating subgroup of $S_4$),
- $Dic_{12}$ (dicyclic group of order $12$),
- $C_6 \times C_2$ (direct product of $C_6$ and $C_2$).

1. Since $S_3$ is not abelian, we can exclude the groups of order $12$ which are abelian (in this case: $C_{12}$ and $C_6 \times C_2$.
2. According to [Groupprops](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Alternating_group:A4), the only normal subgroups of $A_4$ are $\{ e \}, V_4, A_4$ (where $V_4$ is the Klein four group). None of them have cardinality $2$, so $A_4$ is also not possible.
3. We can write $D_6 = C_6 \rtimes C_2$, and if $r$ is a generator of $C_6$, we can take $H = \langle r^3 \rangle \times \{ e \} \simeq C_2$. With that choice, we have $G/H \simeq C_3 \rtimes C_2 = S_3$ as desired.
4. Using [Groupprops](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Dicyclic_group#Cases) again, we see that $Dic_{12} = C_3 \rtimes C_4$. If $x$ is a generator of $C_4$, choose $H = \{ e \} \times \langle x^2 \rangle$, it should be $G/H \simeq C_3 \rtimes C_2 = S_3$ again.

Therefore, $D_6$ and $Dic_{12}$ are the only two possible choices.

Could you please confirm if this is correct?

Comment: Context: I got this question when I was studying quadratic extensions of Galois groups of cubic polynomials (which have order at most $12$) for my thesis. This question deals with the case when the Galois group of the cubic polynomial is $S_3$. Arguments without the full classification are fine if they can be traced back to the definitions of the named groups of order $12$.

Comment: In case it is for a thesis you don't need to justify it. You can take this result just from the literature and cite it (I am sure it is known). Of course, using the classification is also fine.

Comment: My issue is just my question if my arguments were correct still remains (I could not find the possible quotients of $Dic_{12}$ in the literature, for instance). I just wanted to make sure that my result is correct.

Comment: If the quotient has $6$ elements and is nonabelian, you are done.

Comment: I see that the argument for $D_6$ could be simplified. But what about $Dic_{12}$?

Comment: See [here](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/1/Dic3.html). Consider the quotient  by its center - see right margin! And, yes, 3.) $ D_6=C_2\times S_3$.